# JQuery Validation Plugin - how to add error messages to Title Attribute?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have looked everywhere for the answer to this question and while there are many questions that are similar, none work exactly like I want.

I am using JQuery Validator Plugin for a webform. Due to design constraints, I do not want the error message to be appended to the previous element. Currently, I have it working where it adds a specific class to the input that is invalid, using highlight as well as adding a summary to the bottom of the form. No problems there.

However, I find that this alone is not enough as the user really still has no idea why the particular spot is invalid. I have really no space to automatically display the error message; however, I read in the documentation that you can add the error message to the title attribute which is what I want to do. Quoted from, site:

> An error message displays a hint for the user about invalid elements, and what is wrong. There are three ways to provide error messages. Via the title attribute of the input element to validate, via error labels and via plugin settings (option messages).

However, it does not show how to actually add the error message to the title attribute. So, here is what I have so far, what can I do in this situation?

FYI: I realize that I will have to add the error messages back in instead of having "" as the message.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#popcornOrder").validate({
            rules: {
                fName:      "required",
                lName:      "required",
                street:     "required",
                city:       "required",
                state:      "required",
                zip:        {required: true, ziprange: true},
                accountNum: "required",
                email:      {required: true, email: true},
                pwd:        "required",
                confPwd:    {required: true, equalTo: "#pwd"},
                payment:    "required"
            },
            messages: {
                fName:      "",
                lName:      "",
                street:     "",
                city:       "",
                state:      "",
                zip:        "",
                accountNum: "",
                email:      "",
                pwd:        "",
                confPwd:    "",
                payment:    ""

            },
            highlight:
                function(element) {
                    $(element).addClass('errorBorder');
                },
            unhighlight:
                function(element) {
                    $(element).removeClass('errorBorder');
                },
            invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
                var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
                    if (errors) {
                         var message = errors == 1
                            ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted'
                            : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields. They have been highlighted';
                         $("div.error span").html(message);
                         $("div.error").show();
                         } else {
                        $("div.error").hide();
                    }
             },
             focusInvalid: false
    });
});
```

EDIT: Okay, I did get one step closer: if I add the following line it will add a message to the title attribute (this was just regular ol JQuery), BUT it adds the the message summary to ALL titles. So, the real question then is how to add the specific errors to each of the inputs?

```
$("input").attr("title", message);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to uniquely identify the input.

```
$("input[name=foo]").attr("title", message);
```

Where `foo` is the name of the input. I suspect this will coincide with the name of the rule that was broken (e.g. fName, lName, etc). Obviously you'll need to do this for each error you have.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I suppose it would work that way, and I knew that - I just thought maybe there was an easier way to do it than to write one of these for every input. However, I tried to add the following to the end of the code and I think it might be getting me closer, but still no dice as it adds a title (which is a +1), but the title is [object Object] on each one!`errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     element.attr("title", error);
    }`

Comment: Instead of creating these one by one, in the invalidHandler function, loop through the error messages from your validator and update the title while you do that with the appropriate message.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this yet?

```
errorPlacement: 
    function(error, element) {
        $(element).prop("title", error.text());
    },
```

And to remove it...

```
unhighlight:
    function(element) {
        $(element).removeClass('errorBorder').prop("title", "");
    },
```

Comment: Yes, and I was excited when I was typing it out because I thought for sure it would work. And it does work, but only halfway. It adds a title attribute (as there is not one hard-coded into the HTML already), but for each input that has the error, the title attribute is just [object Object] for some reason.?

Comment: @shelzmike, See my edit... starting with jQuery 1.6, in nearly all cases, `prop()` should be used in place of `attr()`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I am still quite new to JQuery (love it, but still learning). Unfortunately, that still is passing along the same result. There is a title attribute added, but the text is specifically [object Object]. So aggravating.

Comment: Okay, another update. It has something to do specifically with error in .prop("title", error) because when I change error to some text like .prop("title", "Some Text") it actually adds the title attribute properly with "Some Text" as its text.

Comment: @shelzmike, I see you figured it out.  I'm not sure why you can't "self answer"... you should absolutely be able to post an answer.  Otherwise, you can accept my answer... see edit.

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as correct by clicking on the tick on the left side to help out people know whether its correct or not!